# Is the conditional form of a verb treated like a regular verb or a noun/na-adjective?

Tags: conditionals

First of all thanks to everyone helping me out here, i'm already feeling some progress on the learning process, of course there’s a lot of room to improve, but sure it is nice to feel some progress every now and then ^^.

Now to my question, I was going to make a sentence to ask a friend of mine about a grammar point “The difference between using  なんです or just です at the end of a sentence” so I came up with this sentence(which brought me another grammar doubt about the conditional form):

“If someone ask me ‘Felipe, where are you going?’ so, I said ‘I am going to work’  or ‘I am going to work’(don’t know how to express なんです in English). What’s the difference between these sentences?”

`誰かが僕に「フェリペがどこに行っていますの?」と問えばなので、僕は「仕事です」というか、「仕事なんです」というか。これらの文の違いはなんかですか？`

My question is on the first part, If the first part was ending with 「問います」I know for sure that I would use 「ので」instead of 「なので]

but if I had endend with 「問いたい」I’d need to end it with 「なので」because it understood as an i-adjective.

What about the 「問えば」 ending, do I treat it as a verb or a noun/na-adjective? Therefore should I use 「なので」or 「ので」?

I’m sorry for the really long question, I hope I was clear enough, if you could help me in any mistakes on the sentence overall, I’d be grateful!

Thanks a Lot!

Comment: While I refrain from posting an answer, I'll offer a few suggestions to the Japanese in your question: 'to ask' -> 'kiku'; 'to answer' -> 'kotaeru'; -eba followed by 'na no de' is ungrammatical (-tara would fit better here); nanka desu ka -> nan desu ka

Comment: Yeah, I thought it could be the case though. Is there any case where potential (eba) could be followed by dakara, nanode, dakedo? Is it grammatical to end a portion of a sentece with potential (eba) instead of Tara?

Comment: Oh, I just realised that we have a terminology problem here. The -eba form is not a potential form in common parlance (You may be thinking in terms of your own language here). The potential form in Japanese is e.g. 食べる→食べられる、飲む→飲める and means "to be able to do".

Comment: My bad, I corrected it now, it was just a confusion with the names, I do understand both forms. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to limit my answer to your question about what to do with「～ば」and 「ので・なので」

- **問{と}う** as I'm sure you know, means "to ask a question" (like on a test)
- **問えば** means "(*if*) a question were asked" (The 仮定形 of 問う is 問え and then you add the 助詞「ば」to indicate something like, "if it were the case that...")
- **ので・なので** generally mean "because" or "as a result" in English.

The problem is that 「ば」is a conjunction (接続助詞) and「ので・なので」is also a conjunction. This means that **they can't be used next to one another grammatically**.

Your original example sentence has a similar problem with the English grammar. I remember you said a while ago that English isn't your native language so I'm not trying to criticize you at all, you've obviously worked hard to use English so well :)

> “**If** someone *asked*/*asks* me "Felipe, where are you going?", **so** I said "I am going to work" or "I am going to work". What’s the difference between these sentences?”

You can make this clause using "if" ***or*** using "so", but you *can't use both* in the same clause this way.

So, the following are OK in English:

- **If** someone *asks* me "Felipe, where are you going?", and I say "I am going to work" (then) ...
- Someone *asked* me "Felipe, where are you going?", **so** I said "I am going to work".

Likewise, the following are OK in Japanese:

- 生年月日を問われれ**ば**…  "**If** I were asked my birth date, ..."
- 生年月日を問われた**ので**…  "I was asked my birth date, **so**..."

But you can't use these two words together like in the OP example sentence.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this, it's definitely a messy question, I'm sorry

Comment: I just have one more doubt, about the potential form, is ok to end a sentence with it? Let's say two people are talking 「大丈夫ですか？」「ちょっと眠れば」. Can I keep it this simple or should I do the full 「ちょっと眠れば、大丈夫になります」？Thanks!!!

Comment: 「ちょっと寝れたら」might sound more natural, but I don't see any problem grammatically.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira 「ちょっと眠ったら/眠れば/寝たら/寝れば(+大丈夫です/大丈夫だと思います)。」 sounds more natural to me. 眠ったら、眠れば、寝たら、寝れば (= "If I sleep") are not potential. Their potential forms are [眠]{ねむ}れたら、眠れれば、[寝]{ね}られたら、寝られれば (= "If I **can** sleep"), respectively

Comment: Hi chocolate, I messed up a little I meant conditional, not potential, too many terms to remember x.x . I am going to edit the question, thanks a lot